# Why were the TWA TriStar middle seats smaller than the aisle seats?

Tags: cabin-design, seats, lockheed-tristar

I was watching an [old TWA advert](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T1_qBeD6oUg) and a question came up:
why were the [L-1011 TriStar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_L-1011_TriStar) middle seats smaller than the aisle seats?

[image]

Comment: Probably to allow better viewing of the projector screen up front.

Comment: Its possible it was done only for this advertisement, since [I can't find any interior shot with the same arrangement](https://www.google.com/search?q=l1011&safe=off&espv=2&biw=1554&bih=776&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjG5uXkvNzNAhXH4yYKHYzaBV0Q_AUIBigB#safe=off&tbm=isch&q=l1011+interior) on Google images at least.

Answer (score 8):

Those seats aren't smaller! TWA had fold over seatbacks, resulting in a nice table for the seat next to you if the flights weren't full. They are the exact same size as the other seats. Also, those things down the centerlines between the seats were coat closets.

Later replaced by a full width seat when they went from 2-4-2 to 2-5-2 in their last configurations.